# why ajax in an external js file is not working in codeigniter framework

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am created a external js file for plotting a graph in codeigniter. My controller is reached in js file. but the ajax in that file is not supported. here i am attaching the ajax code.`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
        $.ajax({
            url : baseurl + "Welcome/pidiagram",
                type : "GET",
                success : function (data) {
                    alert("data");
                        console.log(data);
                }
        )};
    });
```

the control is reached inside the document ready function but not inside the ajax.

so please help me.....

Comment: *external js file* specify the path

Comment: "assets/js/pages/pidiagram.js" .  pidiagram.js  is my js file for graph plotting. controller pass the value to this js file.

Comment: try adding `<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/pages/pidiagram.js`

Comment: then what you're trying to access with this `url : baseurl+"Welcome/pidiagram",` ??

Comment: "Welcome/pidiagram" here Welcome is my main controller and pidiagram is the function for passing value from controller to the js file

Comment: I want to access value from "Welcome/pidiagram" and plot graph with respect to that value. But my $.ajax({}) is not working in my program.

Comment: add controller code

Comment: public function pidiagram()
        {
           $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('piechart');  
            $res1 = $this->piechart->piechart();
            
            echo json_encode($res1);
          
        }

Comment: Actually, you have to trigger the ajax call some events. Can you tell me when you want to trigger the ajax? I mean onload or any other event??

Comment: i want to automatically load the ajax when user entering to the page

Comment: how did you add `$this->load->model('piechart')` ?? Did you create any custom helpers ??

Comment: 'piechart' is my model for fetching data from the database and that data is pass to the controller. Then the controller pass the data to the js using json_encode.

Comment: i check my code using alert() function. The alert is working inside the document.ready function(). but it is not working inside the $.ajax function. then i conclude that my ajax is not working in my js file

Comment: i cant understand what is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely your `js` File won't get parsed by PHP since you outsourced it in an own file

the only thing i'd suggest here is, to add your `base URL` as an attribute to the html tag e.g.

```
<html data-base-url="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
```

and after that its pretty simple

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var baseurl = $('html').attr('data-base-url');
    $.ajax({
        url : baseurl + "Welcome/pidiagram",
            type : "GET",
            success : function (data) {
                alert("data");
                    console.log(data);
            }
    )};
});
```